# How to change position of the Windows 7 TaskBar

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, taskbar

I have a program with Form, which size is the same as the Windows TaskBar. The Form must be placed over the Windows 7 TaskBar. I made this, but the user can choose where to place the Form (left, right, bottom, top). I want to change the position of the Windows TaskBar at the same position of the Form of my Application. Is there a way to do this with C# or VB?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to clarify what you wish to achieve, its difficult to parse from your question as it stands.

Comment: if i might comment on what your trying to do, if a program i was using changed the position of the taskbar (and im assuming thats not the purpose of the program)and not change it back after i closed it, i would be quite annoyed with said program

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you do because no user is ever going to elect to run such a program.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the Taskbar programmatically, but only to the preset fixed positions it allows (i.e. Bottom, Left, Right, Top).

Example [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/247701-moving-windows-takbar).

Comment: Thank you very much, but the code does not work on Windows 7. I don't know why? People says that it works on Win XP.